Impact of comparison function on upper_bound and lower_bound
I would like to understand the impact of the comparison function (< or <=) on both lower_bound and upper_bound functions.
Consider this program:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;


int main() {
        vector<int> v = {0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

        auto it1 = lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 3, [](int a, int b) {return a < b;});
        auto it2 = lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 3, [](int a, int b) {return a <= b;});
        auto it3 = upper_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 3, [](int a, int b) {return a < b;});
        auto it4 = upper_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 3, [](int a, int b) {return a <= b;});


        cout << distance(v.begin(), it1) << endl;
        cout << distance(v.begin(), it2) << endl;
        cout << distance(v.begin(), it3) << endl;
        cout << distance(v.begin(), it4) << endl;

        return 0;
}

this result is:
3
8
8
3

Could anybody explain this results?
Could we say that lower_bound with < is equivalent to upper_bound with <= all the time?
Same question for (lower_bound, <=) and (upper_bound, <).

I'm pretty sure the comparison requires strict ordering, so <= means you're already in trouble.

Note that <= does not satisfy the strict weak ordering requirement.

@StephenNewell and G.M. - It only needs to fulfill the requirements of BinaryPredicate so it doesn't require strict weak ordering. I had to check myself :-)

@TedLyngmo - Yeah, I found the same thing on cppreference, but I swear I saw strict ordering was required somewhere else. Of course now I can't find it, so maybe it's a case of phantom memories on my part.

@StephenNewell I thought so too, but I guess these *_bound functions are among the few exceptions.

Roughly speaking, any algorithm in the C++ library that does searching or ordering/sorting (std::sort, upper_bound, etc), involving a binary predicate to test ordering, requires that predicate to satisfy the strict weak ordering requirement.   <= does not satisfy that requirement.   Using it causes undefined behaviour.


Could anybody explain this results?

I'll try by describing what they do and by showing a table:

std::lower_bound - Returns the first iterator iter in [first, last) where bool(comp(*iter, value)) is false.
std::upper_bound - Returns the first iterator iter in [first, last) where bool(comp(value, *iter)) is true.




alg.
0
1
2
3
3
3
3
3
4
5
6
7





lower: *iter < 3
T
T
T
F








3 < 3 first false


lower: *iter <= 3
T
T
T
T
T
T
T
T
F



4 <= 3 first false


upper: 3 < *iter
F
F
F
F
F
F
F
F
T



3 < 4 first true


upper: 3 <= *iter
F
F
F
T








3 <= 3 first true




Could we say that lower_bound with < is equivalent to upper_bound with <= all the time? [and vice versa]

As long as the range is partitioned according to bool(comp(elem, value)) (lower_bound) and bool(comp(value, elem)) (upper_bound) using both < and <=, as it is in your case, then yes. As you can hopefully see above, *iter < 3 will then find the first false when 3 <= *iter finds the first true and vice versa. You get:
*iter < value == !(value <= *iter) and *iter <= value == !(value < *iter)

You changed the algorithm in the wrong direction. Using <= in the comparator is just like telling to the opposite to the upper_/lower_bound(). If you do the algorithm by hand on the first iteration you'll face a dillema - you found 3, but the comparator says to you - "Just keep going". So you have a result that you can find 3 because the comparator tells you to skip values equal to your target.
